# Which preposition should be there after "part" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> A.  Making grammatical and speech mistakes is often a necessary part **in**
>   reaching language proficiency.
>
> B. Making grammatical and speech mistakes is often a necessary part **of**
>   reaching language proficiency.
>
> C. Making grammatical and speech mistakes is often a necessary part **to**
>   reach language proficiency.

Do they all mean the same and which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

**of** is the only valid preposition when using [part](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/part) in this specific context.

You can **take part in** (participate in) some activity, but I think this usage only applies to people, not to inanimate things like "speech mistakes" can be the subject in this usage.

You can also have **a part to play** (take a role) in something: note that **to** is an infinitive marker, not a preposition. This usage could be applied to a thing, and so it could be fitted into your sentence like this:

> Making grammatical and speech mistakes often has **a part to play** in reaching language proficiency.

[Here is an Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=part%20of%2C%20part%20in%2C%20part%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpart%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpart%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpart%20to%3B%2Cc0) showing the possibilities.